# проблема с подключением с DB , PHP PDO

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo

Привет всем, у меня проблема с пдо , хочу подключится к базе, -->
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'wm65389_rafael'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/wm65389/domains/online-xaxer.xyz/public_html/db.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /home/wm65389/domains/online-xaxer.xyz/public_html/db.php(18): PDO->__construc

вот код в db.php

```
private  function connect(){
    $config = require_once 'config.php';

    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['name'].';charset='.$config['charset'];
    $t1 = $config['username'];
    $t2 = $config['$password'];

    print_r($config);
    $this -> link = new PDO($dsn, $t1, $t2);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Проверьте имя пользователя и пароль к нему. И учитесь гуглить в первую очередь.

Comment: имя и пароль правильны

Comment: Хост проверяли? На некоторых хостингах не localhost.

Comment: да проверил))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас здесь ошибка

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['name'].';charset='.$config['charset'];
$t1 = $config['username'];
$t2 = $config['$password'];
```

**$password**

Comment: аааааааааа,спасибо,незаметил

Comment: Если вопрос решен - закрывайте "вопрос")

Comment: ok da zakroyu seychas